# Sending an e-mail at a later date in RoR

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a bit new to Rails and have been trying to figure out how to use workers and jobs to send an e-mail at a later date. Currently, I've incorporated a regular mailer to send confirmation emails to new users in my application. However, I'm trying to find a way to send e-mails at a later date as well.

I know this question has been asked a lot on SO, but can anyone guide me on how to actually do this? I have tried using the delayed_jobs gem and resque/redis, but the documentation hasn't been updated for a year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a cron to send those mails? If you're already familiar with sending out mails, scheduling your mailouts should be easy. Check out [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever).

To make things even easier, here's the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby).

Comment: Isn't a cron inefficient and sometimes wonky? To give you some context, I'm trying to create my own version of kickstarter where they send emails in the last 48 hours. I've read in a few posts online that crons are unreliable sometimes whereas workers have more failsafes.

Comment: Yes, I agree. If you think you have heavy or long-running processes involved, then you're most likely better with worker processes. You can check messaging/queueing systems such as RabbitMQ.